# IQueryable<T> on mongoDB '$project or $group does not support {document}

Tags: c#, mongodb, iqueryable

I am getting this issue after running Select on IQueryable

> '$project or $group does not support {document}.'

```
public Interface IVideo
{
   ....
   public string File { get; set;} 
   public bool Categorized { get; set;}
   public IMovie Movie { get; set;} 
   ....
}

public Interface IMovie
{
   ....
   public List<string> Langauge {get; set;} 
   ....
}

public static Dictionary<string, int> GetLanguage(string isp)
{
    //Repository.GetVideos() is IQueryable<IVideo>
    var videos = Repository.GetVideos().Where(q => q.Categorized && (
                                                       q.File == isp ||
                                                       q.File == "st"));

    var language = videos.SelectMany(q => q.Movie.Language).Select(e => e);
    var ql = from x in language
        group x by x
        into g
        let count = g.Count()
        orderby count descending
        select new {g.Key, count}; // issue is here

    return ql.ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.count);
}
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Fix

As MongoDB does not support grouping or projection just ToList the language available

```
public static Dictionary<string, int> GetLanguage(string isp)
{
    //Repository.GetVideos() is IQueryable<IVideo>
    var videos = Repository.GetVideos().Where(q => q.Categorized && (
                                                       q.File == isp ||
                                                       q.File == "st"));
    //ToList() added here
    var language = videos.SelectMany(q => q.Movie.Language).Select(e => e).ToList();
    var ql = from x in language
        group x by x
        into g
        let count = g.Count()
        orderby count descending
        select new {g.Key, count}; 

    return ql.ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.count);
}
```